# regex in $match mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to search data in MongoDB. Basically it should search starts with/includes/contains
I have collection :

```
[{
Name: "test",
Code: "LP1234"
},
{
Name: "test1",
Code: "1234"
},
{
Name: "test2",
Code: "lp2277"
}]
```

Now from Node JS I am searching the data using $match. So if I search I need out put in the following pattern:
Search input: 12
Result should be :

```
[{
Name: "test",
Code: "LP1234"
},
{
Name: "test1",
Code: "1234"
}]
```

Search Input(small case): lp
Output should be:

```
[{
Name: "test",
Code: "LP1234"
},
{
{
Name: "test2",
Code: "lp2277"
}]
```

Please let me know how aggregate query can be formed with $match.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      resultObject: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$Code",
          regex: "12",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      resultObject: true
    }
  }
])
```

You can try here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JnyORG8i_Qo